# How to set X-Frame-Options in express.js node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, iframe, embed

I have some static assets that I want to serve inside iframes of several desktop / mobile web clients.

Now, how do I whitelist a specific set of origins to be allowed 
setting of X-Frame-Options headers so that the resource can be embedded as iframes 
inside different desktop / mobile web clients.
and for all other origins denies the access to this resource.

With a little digging I started off with -

```
const app = express();

var allowCrossDomain = function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Authorization');
    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") res.send(200);
    else next();
}
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

Now here how do I set the X-Frame-Options header with the whitelisted origin values here -

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should import [helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet) and use [frameguard](https://github.com/helmetjs/frameguard) to get some origins whitelisted. More on this topic: [MDN X-FRAME-OPTIONS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) [Best Practice Security](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html)

Comment: According to MDN 'x-Frame-Options' is obsolete in modern browsers, and it's better to avoid using it:

https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/frameguard/ (read 'allow from' section)

Comment: I downvoted this since it's overkill to import an entire library to accomplish something so trivial (despite what Express recommends)

Answer (score 11):

all you need is [helmet](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/)

```
npm install helmet --save 

const express = require('express')
const helmet = require('helmet')

const app = express()

app.use(helmet.frameguard())
```

Comment: if I add only app.use(helmet()) is it ok?? am using helmet version 3.21.3

Comment: @BijaySingh yes that should do..according to the doc https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/

Answer (score 0):

To address Steven's concern, you can install the frameguard package [only](https://www.npmjs.com/package/frameguard)

```
   npm install helmet --save 

   const frameguard = require("frameguard");

   // Don't allow me to be in ANY frames:
   app.use(frameguard({ action: "deny" }));

   // Only let me be framed by people of the same origin:
    app.use(frameguard({ action: "sameorigin" }));
    app.use(frameguard()); // defaults to sameorigin
```