# Refused to display 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/files/xxx.pdf' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin' in Node Express API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

As answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46998540/how-to-set-x-frame-options-in-express-js-node-js) applied the solution but still not able to bind the PDF in an iframe of other origin project. See the [console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lr1vi.png) I am getting.

Solution I applied :

```
app.use(helmet.frameguard({
  action: 'allow-from',
  domain: 'http://localhost:4200'
}))
```

Is there any other issue or am I doing some mistake?

Thanks

Comment: You're allowing the port `4200` but the file is at port `8000`?

Comment: My front-end project is running on http://localhost:4200. and NodeExpress API is on http://127.0.0.1:8000. so I set the allow-from: 'http://localhost:4200'.

Comment: Some browsers do not support Helmet.js.

Comment: @Raymond care to elaborate? What browser doesn't support what.

Comment: @JuanMendes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options#Browser_compatibility Safari, ALLOW-FROM.

Comment: @Raymond Thanks. The problem is not Helmet.js then? It's Safari not supporting ALLOW-FROM? I was confused since Helmet.js runs server side and not Safari.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

Some browsers do not support Helmet.js features, the ALLOW-FROM feature. **Such as, Safari which you are maybe using.**

Check compatibility for ALLOW-FROM here: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options#Browser_compatibility)

```
app.use(frameguard({ action: 'sameorigin' })) // Defaults
```

To just serve static files from a directory in express use [(Express Servering Static Files)](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html):

Create a public folder, put items into it.

You would then use **http://localhost:8000/name.pdf**

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Since the path is relative if you launch your application from another directory, you can go with this approach.

You would then use **http://localhost:8000/static/name.pdf**

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

Comment: But How can I allow the specific origin in frameguard. I want to display static files of NodeExpressJS API server in my other front-end project. But its showing the sameorigin error.

Comment: @Vijay some browsers do not support ALLOW-FROM such as Safari.

Comment: Ok. But Is there any other solution to bind PDF in iframe of NodeExpress API static files?

Comment: @Vijay yes, check my post. Create a public folder, and put the PDF into there. And then view it http:://localhost:8888/name.pdf. https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Solved. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Vijay No problem.